# How to record personal portfolio appreciation?

Tags: accounting, portfolio

I'd like to know how to record for the appreciation of my investment portfolio.
The idea of not recording it; and then recording it as revenue once I sell it seems a bit off to me.
I plan to hold my shares and bonds for a long time, possibly never selling them; Thus the recognition of the increase in value using that method will happen very far out into the future if I even ever sell.

One solution I've found is to do it just like depreciation with the "Accumulated Appreciation." and -"Appreciation Revenue.".
It did sound like a good idea to me however, once I was implementing it, I encountered some problems and didn't found any answers for them:

- What to do if the market price goes down? Should I debit "Appreciation Revenue."?
- And how to record it on my income statement? I've seen people say that you shouldn't record appreciation on it at all because it's not a "normal gain". But the increase/decrease in value will happen every month since I never plan to sell, so in that sance it would be normal.

This is for my personal bookkeeping that I do on my own in Excel.
The accounting periods last one month, with an additional annual report.
I would love to be able to see the current market value of my portfolio on the balance sheet.

Comment: I collect these amounts - plus and minus - under an account named 'Unrealized Gains/Losses'; then, when I finally 'realize' the gains/losses, I enter a entry that moves them to real gains. Works fine for me. Not sure though if that is an generally accepted approach.

Comment: @Aganju  I think your comment would make a good answer,

Comment: @Aganju I implemented it, but so far it's showing the gross unrealized gains (just the value increase, no taxes or fees), should I change it to net unrealized gains?